# Unable to restore nuget packages on Sitecore8.2 build

Tags: sitecore8, nuget-package-restore, helix

I'm trying to setup a MVC 5 Sitecore 8.2(helix) project but not able to restore the Nuget packages.

This is the error I get when installing from command line

Restoring NuGet package Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.1.0.7.
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.0.7' of package 'Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions'.

[14:11:41] Unable to find version '1.0.7' of package 'Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions'.

Trying from Visual studio I get this

[image]

I have added the following package sources Nuget v2, Nuget v3, Sitecore v2, Sitecore v3

[image]

I upgraded my Node version to Node-v10.20.1-x64 and gulp version 6.14.4 but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

That package no longer exists on NuGet. It's [from Habitat](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/master/src/Foundation/SitecoreExtensions/code) which is no longer maintained and probably never should have been released to NuGet in the first place. I would recommend adding the extensions that you are using into your own foundation project.